# Track amount of clicks user clicks button

Tags: android

I was wandering if there was any way to track the amount of clicks a user clicks a button.

I am creating a game and the user will only be allowed to take 5 turns. After these turns the user has lost the game.

I need to create maybe an if statement where the amount of clicks the user takes reaches > 5 then the user has lost. Is this possible.

I appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Edit:

```
Button link2Btn = (Button)findViewById( R.id.answerSelected );
```

link2Btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
{
    i++;

getAnswer();
    }

The get Answer method works fine except the if i > 5 statement within get Answer which is:

```
else if(i>5){
    correctAnswer.setText("You have lost");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag variable and make an increment over  a button press.
like

```
int i=0;
```

when button pressed

```
i++;
```

Now your condition

```
if(i>5){}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried this. I added int i = o; as a variable. I then put i++; into the onClick method and then the if statement if(i>5){} within a method. This is not working, I have added this within other if statements that do checking, they work but it doesn't show the message after 5 clicks.

Comment: Are you using `i` as global variable.

Comment: Yes I have initialized the variable under public class as i=o;.

Comment: Is the code executing on `onClick`/Can you please show me your code?

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes the code is executing on click, I have edited the code in above.

Comment: Naming the variable `i` might be unwise; it would be very easy to use it by mistake as a loop variable somewhere else in your code. Name it something meaningful like `attempts`. If that doesn't do it, perhaps you need to post your entire onClick() method. It sounds like there's quite a bit of logic there and maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: `public void onClick(View v) { if(i>5){correctAnswer.setText("You have lost");} else{getAnswer(); i++} }` ,Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this has worked great. It doesn't exactly show 'you have lost' in the 6th button press it shows it on the 7th button press when I set it to 5. But setting i>3 allows it to be on the 5th button press. Thanks again.